# How to add child row details in DataTable after converting it from ordinary html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am converting an ordinary table to a dataTable. Now I have a lot columns and I don't want horizontal scrolling . Is there any way to add child rows to data table after converting it from ordinary table ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add child rows, check out this example on [Child rows (show extra / detailed information)](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html); Be sure to add all the necessary Javascript library files and you should e good to go.